# JS fake trusted events - automatic login after autofill by browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want my site to automatically log the user in once the browser auto-filled the credentials in the login form.

I'm able to detect those auto-fill events via CSS transitions and onAnimationStart on the JS side but I can't receive the credentials until a trusted event is fired by the user.

Is there any way to spoof this? Or even a completely different approach to achieve this?

Comment: I think from a security point of view, it's rather better that the user needs to manually acknowldege his credentials. => if he chooses the wrong auto fill by mistake he doesn't want to automatically send the credentials of another website to your website

Comment: Not an expert, but i am pretty sure that you cannot change the value of `isTrusted` in javascript. Relevant docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted and maybe for some more context https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=637248

Comment: In addition to what @user3252327 said - the automatic sign in would prevent using different credentials. If they have an alternative user or it's actually a shared computer or anything else. Overall, I think you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at your hands. Because what about users who *don't* store their credentials in the browser - should they not be logged in? Do you perhaps not just want to keep the login session+cookie live for longer instead?

Comment: they can obviously enter their credentials manually. but fair that's some good points for a production site. I was only playing around and was curious whether it was possible